Open a url in Firefox private tab using intents in Android
I want to open a url (that keeps changing based on some logic) in Firefox android app in private mode (incognito equivalent of chrome).
I am able to open a url in normal mode by doing -
private void open(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.setClassName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.fenix.IntentReceiverActivity");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

I am also able to open Firefox with private mode active (this does not open url like previous code does, just private mode) by doing -
private void open(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.mozilla.fenix.OPEN_PRIVATE_TAB", Uri.parse(url));
    intent.setClassName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.fenix.IntentReceiverActivity");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

but I am not able to open a url in private mode.
How can I achieve it?
Thanks
